# How to backup program data, such as Chromium and Thunderbird etc?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, backup

What do you recommend to backup, if you don't trust your linux system (I have the problem that sometimes I can't boot linux because of graphic-card issues).

At the moment I'm using `Back In Time` and backup `/`. I think this is a complete backup of my system right now?

Comment: Backing up your home folder should suffice.

Comment: What exactly is saved (and what is not) if I just backup my home-folder?

Comment: @Ashu assuming private files are in home ;)

Comment: @refle all your private settings are stored in home in hidden directories. And if you did not change it also your desktop, pictures, downloads and documents directory. System files are not needed: for a home use computer fixing the problem that occurs or a re-install will be faster ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind aha right, but isnt that the default case?

Comment: Yeah but I myself are used to store private data on a separate disc called /discworld ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Backup Thunderbird**

Copy the below folder [to show the hidden folder press  "Ctrl+H"]

```
/home/your user/.thunderbird/
```

**Backup Chromium**

just sign in with your google account or copy the below folder

```
/home/your user/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Comment: When backing up thunderbird, you might want to backup the ~/.purple directory too. (Don't know exactly what it is for, but it somehow has something to do with thunderbird)

Answer (score 1):

This is about Chromium. If you want to save all your bookmarks in Chromium, you better connect your browser with your google account. Then you can access them anywhere you like.